# Setting a basecls in Extjs breaks draggable containers

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework, extjs6

I want to crate a container with a specific baseCls that's also draggable. Unfortunately it seems that if i add a basCls then my container is no longer draggable. Can anyone help me out so that I can have a baseCls set and also have a draggable container.

This is a fiddle with an example of it being broke. If you comment out the baseCls it will work correctly: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22b3

```
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
        title: 'Hello',
        baseCls: 'cf-core-widget cf-core-widget-container',
        width: 200,
        html: '<p>World!</p>',
        style: 'border: 1px solid black',
        draggable: true,
        renderTo: document.body
    });
```

Comment: You're better off just not using `baseCls`, can you just use `cls` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `baseCls` of a `container` is `'x-component'` as per [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-baseCls). If you still need the component behaviour, you should keep that one and only add others as required.

```
baseCls: 'x-component cf-core-widget cf-core-widget-container',
```